# C-strdup memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have this code here and when I run it it works normally but at the end it throws me a memory leak from the strdup function.
Could I ask for some advice, I'm at my wits end.

*My code*

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

void modify(const char *input, char *output) {
    int lng = strlen(input);
    for (int i = 0; i < lng - 1; ++i) {
        output[i] = input[i];
    }
}

typedef struct {
    int index;
    char *ticker;
    float start;
    float end;
    int volume;
} Akcie;

void akcie_init(Akcie *akcie, int index, char *ticker, float start, float end, int volume) {
    akcie->index = index;
    akcie->ticker = ticker;
    akcie->start = start;
    akcie->end = end;
    akcie->volume = volume;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Akcie *akcie;
    char *com;
    if (argc == 3) {
        int cislo = atoi(argv[2]);
        akcie = (Akcie *) malloc(cislo * sizeof(Akcie));
        char buf[101];
        char lo[100];
        char *toto[5];
        printf("<html>\n"
               "<body>\n"
               "<div>\n"
               "</div>\n"
               "<ul>\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < cislo; ++i) {
            fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin);
            modify(buf, lo);
            com = strdup(lo);
            int j = 0;
            char *colo = strtok(com, ", ");
            while (colo != NULL) {
                toto[j] = colo;
                colo = strtok(NULL, ", ");
                j++;
            }
            akcie_init(&akcie[i], akcie[i].index = atoi(toto[0]), akcie[i].ticker = toto[1],
                       akcie[i].start = atof(toto[2]), akcie[i].end = atof(toto[3]), akcie[i].volume = atoi(toto[4]));
        }
        for (int l = cislo - 1; l >= 0; l--) {
            printf("<li> Day: %d, ticker: %s start: %.2f, end: %.2f, volume: %d </li> \n", akcie[l].index,
                   akcie[l].ticker, akcie[l].start, akcie[l].end, akcie[l].volume);
        }
        free(com);
        free(akcie);
        printf("</ul>\n"
               "</body>\n"
               "</html>");

    } else {
        printf("Wrong parameters");
    }
}
```

*Output + Memory leak*

```
└─$ ./main AMC 10 <test-ticker-404.stdin
<html>
<body>
<div>
</div>
<ul>
<li> Day: 5, ticker: META start: 458.51, end: 462.19, volume: 328371639 </li> 
<li> Day: 4, ticker: GOOGL start: 687.75, end: 690.60, volume: 84021759 </li> 
<li> Day: 4, ticker: META start: 462.58, end: 458.51, volume: 536291890 </li> 
<li> Day: 3, ticker: AAPL start: 408.75, end: 411.80, volume: 737451730 </li> 
<li> Day: 3, ticker: GOOGL start: 687.98, end: 687.75, volume: 70074900 </li> 
<li> Day: 3, ticker: META start: 461.47, end: 462.58, volume: 275445389 </li> 
<li> Day: 2, ticker: AAPL start: 408.15, end: 408.75, volume: 475850689 </li> 
<li> Day: 2, ticker: GOOGL start: 685.68, end: 687.98, volume: 91902769 </li> 
<li> Day: 2, ticker: META start: 458.37, end: 461.47, volume: 19824825 </li> 
<li> Day: 1, ticker: AAPL start: 403.28, end: 408.15, volume: 71579480 </li> 
</ul>
</body>

=================================================================
==5879==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
                                                                                                                                                             
Direct leak of 277 byte(s) in 9 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7f4b1487077b in __interceptor_strdup ../../../../src/libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cpp:439                                                    
    #1 0x55dd86eca65b in main main.c:46
    #2 0x7f4b14429209  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29209)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 277 byte(s) leaked in 9 allocation(s).
```

I was thinking to save the com in each stock and then at the end delete all those com indicators in the stock. Or even completely differently, not allocate memory on the heap, but store those names directly in the share, in the form of a static array. But I don't know how to do that. Thank you for the solution

Comment: OT but your call to akcie_init() is very weird. You're calling that function to set the structure fields, but you're also setting them in the actual invocation itself. So you're setting them all twice. Functionally harmless, but very, very odd and pointless.

Answer (score 4):

It's a very obvious leak as you call `com = strdup(lo);` in an inner loop but only `free` in an outer loop.

The most basic rule of memory leaks: the number of `malloc`/`strdup` calls must match the number of `free` calls.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But where and how to write it in the code?

Comment: @Lukasko You need to save the start address of each string originally pointed at by `com` somewhere for freeing later. For example each item in the `akcie` array could store the start address, then you could call clean-up of it in a loop before freeing `akcie` itself.